# How to append predicted probability output to pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I am running a classification model, and as per my specific requirements, I am using

```
clf.predict_proba('test.csv')
```

My prediction is multi class classification and the output is something like:

```
array([[0.57992155, 0.25998281, 0.16009564],
   [0.58711277, 0.25100034, 0.16188689],
   [0.58711277, 0.25100034, 0.16188689],
   [0.58711277, 0.25100034, 0.16188689],
   [0.58711277, 0.25100034, 0.16188689],
   [0.58711277, 0.25100034, 0.16188689],
   [0.58503097, 0.25347251, 0.16149652],
   [0.58711277, 0.25100034, 0.16188689],
   [0.58503097, 0.25347251, 0.16149652],
   [0.58711277, 0.25100034, 0.16188689]])
```

Now, if it would have been a binary classification, I use the following code to append the results to pandas dataframe:

```
test['output'] = y_pred.tolist()
```

But in this case, where the desired output dataframe should show the probabilities for each class like:

```
customer_id     class_1       class_2       class_3
    1        0.57992155    0.25998281    0.16009564
```

what should be the code for it?

Thanks for help:)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

pandas magic indexing to the rescue:

```
df[['class_1','class_2','class_3']] = clf.predict_prob('test.csv')
```